# PCB markings - What components might have component designators TB1, TB2 etc?

Tags: pcb, identification, components

Looking at a PCB, there are 4 components marked TB1, TB2 etc.

I believe that the markings mean terminal board. What exactly is a terminal board?

---

Update: Unfortunately I cannot show a picture of the actual components. It looks very similar to a fuse like this. No markings on the component.

[image: Photo of components]

Comment: Can you show us a picture? Markings aren't always standard, but it would help to see what these components are.

Comment: Why did you guess Terminal Board - how do you know it's not tube 1, transistor B1 or Thyristive Biggatron 1?

Comment: @RonBeyer you are right, I removed my answer.

Comment: @RonBeyer Unfortunately I cannot. It looks very similar to a fuse like this. No markings on the component. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/bbfV0K4VBR3mGKM3LdPpiT2eLh47kv7jajAz4qphiLjgyEZUTItHqWvsjGcPFpuyhqMv1DMQgFX9TCi1wY0KDfwaeal14BUdADBCeiVZph3b--vnPLVaAuOm_BmFjLH4ipVlB18ZPDO_-Y2DN9waiwVRcyAtb9YwlXuh4uTR9xlCDVUW3xMV6o84h00BORExzHGG7Oa0xCN7_AeWzctJ

Comment: It could be terminal block, which is typically a connector which accepts wire connections without solder.  Is it a bare PCB?  If not, what is/was in those locations?

Comment: I know what a terminal block/strip is I have never heard terminal board being used. From this table it appears that terminal strip / terminal board are synonymous. https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3-blogs.mentor.com/tom-hausherr/files/2011/05/table-1-standard-ref-des-for-schematic-symbols.png So I think the correct answer is indeed a terminal block. But in my case the component on the board is definitely not a terminal block. As per the answer below thermal breaker seems the most likely.

Comment: @MikeSeeds - Hi, I believe my update to your question captures the essence of [your comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480009/pcb-markings-what-is-a-terminal-board#comment1219446_480009). If not, please edit the question to change it, as needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I might guess they are polyfuses© ® so perhaps TB1,TB2 could be  SMD Thermal Breakers